# Div tag to encapsulate li tags

Tags: css

We have a navigation menu built by `<ul>` and `<li>` tags using CSS. Such that sub-menu shows up when user hovers over a menu item.

I am trying to add border to the menu and sub-menus. Can I encapsulate all `<li>` elements in a `<div>` elements. I know, `<div>` is not a valid child for `<ul>` but browser (chrome) in this case renders it correctly. As per usecase we do not care much about other browsers.

Is it OK to use `<div>` tag to encapsulate `<li>` tags to add border in this case.

Comment: "div is not a valid child for ul" Then it's not OK, period.

Comment: You can probably do it with CSS only, why don't you post some code, or create a Fiddle?

Comment: Can you give us the html/css so a proper solution can be presented? 

At the end of the day though, if the solution you have works in your usecase, then use it, but know that it's not standards compliant and a chrome update could break it.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not ok, `<div>` tags are not allowed in `<ul>` according to the W3C specs (see [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)).

Why don't you add the `border` css rules to the surrounding `<ul>`/`<ol>` element ? Or you can encapsulate the `<ul>`/`<ol>` element in a `<div>` with borders.